# How to change the dimensions of the scale - move crop rectangle when using UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

Im implementing `capture image` action to **capture the "ID card" and "BUSINESS CARDS"** which are in **3x4 dimensions rectangle in  nature**

when opening working with an UIImagePickerController and setting **`allowsImageEditing = YES;`**

there is a **default cropping frame that is 4x4 square.**

In my case, **I would like to setup that cropping frame to 3x4 for crop images window**.

However, I haven't been able to find a way to change that square frame to rectangle frame  when editing /cropping a photo. Has any of you found a way to do it?

*`MY CLIENT REQUIREMENTS IS need the user to select images that are 3x4 or 2x3 rectangle but the crop rect currently only allows 4x4 square (when allow editing is on).`*

***`How does the "move and scale screen" determine dimensions for its cropbox?`***

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is the size 3x4 but if you are talking about hight and width ratio to be of 3:4 then here is a simple method which will resize the image picked by UIImagePicker in the desired size (which may also be in ratio of 3:4).

```
 - (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Overlay on camera here is source code you can find your answer may be
[Click here](https://github.com/xissburg/XBImageFilters)